# KSH - echo Windows path and special characters

Tags: special-characters, ksh

so I'm receiving a Windows path as argument but since in the path there are special chars I'm having some trouble.

For example if the argument path ($1) is  \test\bla the outout of the script it's "\SLE    esla" (because of the \t and \b)

How can I print the correct path??

Thanks.

p.s.
maybe it's a stupid question but I'm new to ksh

Answer (score 0):

as I said I'm new to ksh but here is the solution:

```
 print -R $arg
```

Using print instead of echo make it possible to avoid the expansion of "\" with the "-R" option